# How do I calculate an offset position from OpenVR's TrackedDevicePose_t?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, openvr

I'm working on 3D digitizing using a Vive controller. I'm using OpenVR to talk to the hardware and `PollNextEventWithPose` to get the controller's pose at the time the user pressed a button. From the pose, I want to calculate a point that's 177mm along the Z axis where our digitizing point is.

Running under Unity, I did something like this:

```
var digitizerPosition = trackedObject.transform.position - trackedObject.transform.forward * 0.177f;
```

Now under OpenVR, `PollNextEventWithPose` gives me a `TrackedDevicePose_t` which contains the field `mDeviceToAbsoluteTracking` which is of type `Valve.VR.HmdMatrix34_t`. Given that matrix, how do I calculate a point along the Z axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of `trackedObject.transform.forward` is:

```
    public static Vector3D Forward(HmdMatrix34_t matrix)
    {
        return new Vector3D(matrix.m2, matrix.m6, matrix.m10);
    }
```